# Checkout Error After Upgrading Magento to 1.8.1

Tags: magento, checkout

I updated my site from Magento 1.8.0 to 1.8.1 and now the checkout process won't proceed after choosing a shipping method. Can someone please advise on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: Please check exception.log, system.log & error reports

Comment: Thanks! checked now and found a "Notice: Undefined variable: i"  in app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/checkout/cart/smart_cart.phtml on line 68.

Comment: The above error has nothing to do with your check out error. Check if there is no JS error in Fire Bug

Comment: I'm getting a "200 OK" status on running /checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ but still can't proceed from Shipping Methods to Payment Methods.

Comment: Solved: In the checkout.xml file of our template, we had to make the following change (change the methods.html file to info.html) The new base template could not override this line and therefore the checkout-payment-method-load div was not writtten. See here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/magneto-v1-8-one-page-checkout-not-loading-payment-information

Comment: Please add this as your answer so that other can get benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. In the checkout.xml file of our template, we had to make the following change (change the methods.html file to info.html) The new base template could not override this line and therefore the checkout-payment-method-load div was not writtten. See here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/magneto-v1-8-one-page-checkout-not-loading-payment-information

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!

It's methods.phtml and info.phtml though just incase anyone else is struggling.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the checkout.xml file from app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/checkout.xml and overwrote the one in our custom directory app/design/frontend/YourName/default/layout with that one, and it fixed the problem. Same with the "white page" PayPal issue. If you have a paypal/ folder in the template folder of your custom skin you also need to replace that with the default one I guess for the paypal issue.